# how do I parse the POST data that gets sent to ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, arrays

I am sending a html form using jquery to ajax, When I send the form to my php file and use `print_r($_POST)` to see what got sent, this is the result:

```
Array
(
    [data] => user_first_name=&user_last_name=&user_birthday_day=&user_birthday_month=&user_birthday_year=&user_addr_street=&user_ad
dr_street_no=&user_addr_city=&user_addr_zip=&user_addr_country=1&user_contact_phone=&user_contact_email=&user_knows_us_from=
)
```

Basically, I get what this is doing, but I am not quite sure what is the best approach to split this string into an array. I know how to use `explode('&', $data)`, but it only explodes my string into an array with values, but numbered keys.
I need `$key => $value` to look like `[user_first_name] => 'Peter'` instead of `[1] => 'user_first_name=Peter'`

How do you solve this problem?

EDIT: This is my ajax code, but it works, so I think it won't really be neccessary here, but still ..

```
  var formData = $('#form-registracia').serialize();

  $.ajax({
     url: '/ajax/registracia.php',
     type: 'POST',
     dataType: 'text',
     data: {'data':formData},
     success: function(data){
        // something will be here
     }
  });
```

Comment: While you could parse that, you should fix the JavaScript so it doesn't double encode the data in the first place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of `data: {'data': formData}` all you need to do is `data: formData`

Answer (score 1):

I see two things that are wrong:

you need to serialize the form data: $(form).serialize()

what you get on the other end is your normal $_POST array

Comment: I believe ``dataType`` is the response from the php script, not what is sent to it. Unless I'm extremely mistaken here, you are wrong. also, I am serializing my data, it's on the first line in the code I pasted. wrong again?

Comment: yeah all you need for the jquery post are 3 parameters url , type & data